# No VaadinSession with Vaadin Fusion

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

I noticed that with Vaadin Fusion endpoints, there seems to be no VaadinSession available. Is this by design? Am I doing anything wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You should not rely on a `VaadinSession` when using Fusion. There might or might not be one available today because of historical reason.

The `VaadinSession` mainly holds Flow UI instances for a given `VaadinServlet`/`VaadinService`. It requires locking before accessing, something you want to avoid with Fusion.

If you want to store values in the session, use the standard `HTTPSession`

Answer (score 3):

Vaadin Fusion does not rely on VaadinSession. In versions prior to 22, a `HttpSession` is created although it is not used by Fusion. As of 22, Fusion can be completely stateless. You can read more about the upcoming stateless authentication here https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/fusion/security/spring-stateless